# AngularJS : Drag and drop from one ui-grid to another or from list to ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want drag and drop functionality between a list to ui-grid or a ui-grid to another ui-grid in angularJS, could some one point me to the right link or approach to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!